# let vs letfn for defining local functions in clojure?

Tags: clojure

When in practice should I use `letfn` vs. `let` for defining local functions?
What about cases where I want both local functions and local non-functions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If all I need is one or a few local functions, I `letfn` them. If I need to define a mix of functions and non-functions, I'll just use a normal `let`. `letfn`ing and `let`ing would be a very verbose way to do this.

However, if you need mutual recursion through your local functions, you'll have to `letfn` them either way.

Short version: use them when you think it looks better, and when it's convenient. There are no hard and fast rules for using either. They are just tools in the Clojure toolbox.

Have fun!

Comment: If you need mutual recursion through local functions you can use named local functins, like `(let [f (fn f [x] ...)] ...)`

Answer (score 25):

Normally it's easier and neater to use `let`: that way you can define a set of both functions and non-functions in a single form, and even refer back to previous definitions:

```
(let [f     (fn [x] ....)
      value (reduce f some-collection)
      foo   bar]
  .....)
```

`letfn` is really only needed when you want to define multiple functions that recursively refer to each other. `let` won't work in this case because it doesn't support recursive references.

Comment: Note that even for simple recursion (a function which body uses itself) a letfn is necessary.

Comment: Yes indeed! Although in a let form that means having either two names for the same fn (one name in the let binding, another in the fn form) or repeating the same name twice, so letfn might be better.